# How to export R data frame into code for sharing?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to write a question for Stack Overflow, and I need to include a data frame so that my data can be replicated. I would like to take a data.frame object, and output code. I.e., I want to take this data.frame:

```
> dat
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

And turn it into this code without having to write it all out myself:

```
> dat <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6))
```

My data.frame is very large, and I need to have a large number of observations for my question to make sense. Therefore it would be great if there is a package that will write that code out for me.

Thanks a lot for any and all advice.

Comment: Use `dput` function. And please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: If the volume of data is what matters, maybe filling a data frame at random is a solution too. For reproduciblity, you can always `set.seed(42)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use `dput` function:

```
dput(dat)
```

If your data.frame is huge, you need to sample it.

And first, if not yet done, please read [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 15):

```
dput(dataframeName)
```

in your case: `dput(dat)`